# Is it legal to discuss Roko's basilisk? (click/research at your own risk)

Tags: freedom-of-speech, first-amendment

I'm a citizen of the United States of America. The First Amendment states that we have the freedom of speech, but I have heard there are limits to that. So that got me thinking: is it legal to discuss Roko's Basilisk, a theoretical being that just thinking about it will be harmful to you. It is technically possible for it to exist, so I was wondering if it's legal in the US to discuss it with one another.

Comment: [Roko's Basilisk](https://wiki.lesswrong.com/wiki/Roko's_basilisk) is a **thought experiment** in **decision theory** - which was **largely rejected**: "Roko's argument was broadly rejected on Less Wrong, with commenters objecting that an agent like the one Roko was describing would have no real reason to follow through on its threat: once the agent already exists, it can't affect the probability of its existence, so torturing people for their past decisions would be a waste of resources."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's nonsense.

Comment: If it were closed, I would vote to reopen. The far-fetched nature of the factual predicate is obvious but not a reason to close. Questions like this are instrumental in analyzing the law and establishing a theoretical framework for the outer limits of our constitutional rights. More questions like this, please.

Comment: oh dear, we should add that to our COVID test questionnaire: Have you thought about Roko's Basilisk in the last 14 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The First Amendment protects all speech, outside a few historically recognized exceptions, which include libel, perjury, incitement, and true threats. There is no exception for speech that injures the speaker himself.